# Validate UUID without RegExp

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

JavaScript `Array.every()` does not work the way I expected

I have been tasked with writing a basic check for **GUID** validity **without using regex**. So all I'm doing is checking if the non-dash characters in the guid string are hexa digits.

```
const isValidGUIDChar = (char) =>  !isNaN(+char) || "abcdef".includes(char.toLowerCase());

// let guid = "123";
// let guid = "abc"
let guid = "abc123";

let isGuidValid = guid.replaceAll('-', '').length === 32 && guid.split().every(isValidGUIDChar);

console.log(isGuidValid);  // returns true for either 'abc' or '123' but false for 'abc123'
```

The results, mention in comment above are counter-intuitive. The `every()` method seems to evaluate to:

"*(every character must either be numeric), or (every character must be from among 'abcdef')*",

whereas what I need, and what seems intuitive, would be for it to evaluate to:

"*(every character) must (either be numeric from among 'abcdef')*"

How can I accomplish the latter?

Comment: Humm ... isn't `"0123456789abcdef"` shorter than `!isNaN(+char) || "abcdef"` ? Also see this: `length === 32`

Comment: You've just forgotten to give `split` a separator, so you get a one-element array with the entire string in it, so `char` is the entire string. More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split If you pass it `""` (or, in modern code, use `[...thestring]`), the check works.

Comment: None of your test strings are 32 characters without dashes?

Comment: @crashmstr - Yeah, to see the problem with `isValidGUIDChar` you have to comment that part out.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I ran a test with a `for` loop and calling the function and everything is `true`, so *is* there a problem with the function or a problem with something elsse?

Comment: @crashmstr - The problem is `guid.split()`, which results in `["123abc"]`, which doesn't pass the `isValidGUIDChar` test (which is designed for individual chars). See my first comment above.

Comment: Also, instead of `guid.split("")` (which BTW is missing a `""`) you could do just `[...guid]`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, but that is not a problem with `isValidGUIDChar` or even the `.every`. Also, they should not be showing code that is an obvious problem that they've "skipped over" themselves.

Comment: @crashmstr - Yeah, bad phrasing on my part in my reply to you. I should have said "To see the problem the OP thinks they have..." :-)

Comment: Your `isValidGUIDChar` function also doesn't match for dash characters, so it will always fail for a valid GUID. Also, just matching each individual character is not going to guarantee you have a valid GUID format, which should be displayed in five groups separated by hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total of 36 characters

Comment: Rookie mistake with the split and -- worse -- with overlooking the length check while testing with non-guid-like strings. But a couple of great changes suggested to what would be working code anyway.

Answer (score 5):

- Your `.split()` is missing `""`  (BTW, use `[...guid]` with [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead)
- Make sure you actually test with 32 char **after!** you replace all dashes
- Use it as a **function** `isGuidValid(guid)` - reusability, remember?

```js
const isHEX = (ch) => "0123456789abcdef".includes(ch.toLowerCase());

const isGuidValid = (guid) => {
  guid = guid.replaceAll("-", ""); // Format it first!
  return guid.length === 32 && [...guid].every(isHEX);
};

console.log(isGuidValid("adec3dc3-7025-4905-b584-d9e64117f2fd"));  // true
console.log(isGuidValid("adec3dc3-7025-4905-b584-d9e64117f2fz"));  // false
console.log(isGuidValid("adec3dc3-7025-4905-b584-d9e64117f2f"));   // false
```

A more robust approach, taking in consideration the [**RFC4122**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122) treating a GIUD/UUID as groups of 8-4-4-4-12 codepoint chars each would be:

```js
const isHEX = h => !isNaN(parseInt(h, 16));
const RFC4122Len = [8, 4, 4, 4, 12];

const isGuidValid = (guid) => {

  // Must have 36 Chars per codepoint (32 + 4 dashes)
  const codePointLenght = [...guid].length;
  if (codePointLenght !== 36) return false;

  // Must have 5 groups
  const groups = guid.split("-");
  if (groups.length !== 5) return false;

  // RFC defines 5 groups of 8-4-4-4-12 codepoints chars each
  const lenMatch = groups.map(gr => [...gr].length).every((len, i) => len === RFC4122Len[i]);
  if (!lenMatch) return false;

  // Finally join groups (without the "-" separators and check for each char is HEX)
  return [...(groups.join(""))].every(isHEX);
};

console.log(isGuidValid("adec3dc3-7025-4905-b584-d9e64117f2fd")); // true
console.log(isGuidValid("adec3dc3-7025-4905-b584-d9e64117f2fz")); // false
console.log(isGuidValid("adec3dc3-7025-4905-b584-d9e64117f2f"));  // false
```

There's more to make it fully RFC4122 compliant but you got the general idea.

Comment: That's wrong. `.every()` also early exits. So does `&&`.

Comment: It happens to the best of us!

Comment: The `replaceAll` also strikes me as bad since having the dashes in the wrong place should also means the GUID is invalid.

Comment: @loganfsmyyh fair points,  but as I said, this is a rudimentary validatior and the question was really about the way I thought .every() wasn't working than about Guids.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the characters are hex digits just use this 3 lines :

```
 function isHex(h)
 {
    let a = parseInt(h, 16);

    return a.toString(16) === h;
 }
```